# Trying to GROUP BY with CASE WHEN THEN - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, case-when

I have three tables `PATH`, `ELEMENTS` and `ELEMENT_DETAILS` with the following structure:

PATH:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

ELEMENTS:

```
ID | PATH_ID | DIRECTION | ELEMENT_DETAILS_ID
1    1         'left'      1
2    1         'right'     2
3    2         'left'      3
4    2         'right'     2
```

ELEMENT_DETAILS:

```
ID | NAME
1    'Henry'
2    'Mark'
3    'John'
```

I would like the result to be like so:

```
ID  | left    |   right
1    'Henry'      'Mark'
2    'John'       'Mark'
```

This is the SQL I have come up with so far:

```
      SELECT path.id, 
             CASE WHEN elements.direction='left' THEN element_details.name
             ELSE NULL END
            as left,
             CASE WHEN elements.direction='right' THEN element_details.name
             ELSE NULL END
            as right,
      FROM elements
      INNER JOIN path on elements.path_id = path.id
      LEFT JOIN element_details on elements.element_details_id = element_details.id
      GROUP BY path.id
      ORDER BY path.id
```

However, this does not work since postgres gives me an error saying `elements.direction should be in group by`. And including `elements.direction` in group_by does not give me aggregation at `path.id` level.

Stuck on this. Can someone please help. 
I am using Postgres version 9.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need aggregation.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT p.id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN e.direction = 'left' THEN ed.name
           END) as left,
       MAX(CASE WHEN e.direction = 'right' THEN ed.name
           END) as right
FROM elements e INNER JOIN
     path p
     ON e.path_id = p.id LEFT JOIN
     element_details ed
     ON e.element_details_id = ed.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id
```